# I want to show a pulse animation on Google Map using .net mvc with help of database using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-ajax

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}


<style>


    #map {
       
           height: 500px;
    
}


</style>


<br />


<br />


<div>
       <select class="form-control"    id="selectedValue"   onchange="GoLocation(this.value)">
      

             @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)
          

                {
             


                 <option value="@item.id">@item.Address</option>
             

                  }
    

</select>


</div>


<br />


<div class="row">


    <div id="map"></div>
    

    <script>

          var map;


        function initMap() {


            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {


                center: { lat: 31.53561, lng: 74.35896 },


                zoom: 12,



            });


        }


              function GoLocation(locationId) {



                  $.get("/Home/GetAllLocationById?Id=" + locationId, function (data, success) {

                      


                          var path = data.Rating == 0 ? "../../icons/icon.png" : 


"../../icons/red_pulse.gif";
                        

                         
                                   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                   
                              
                                   position: { lat: data.Lat, lng: data.Long },
                              


                                       map: map,
                              


                                icon: { url: path, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30) },
                                  


                                    optimized: false


                          });




                            contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                              

                               '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                             


                                   '</div>' +
                             



                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + data.Address + '</h1>' +
                              


                           '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                              





                     '<p><b>' + data.Address + '</b>, is a safe city site node</b>';





                         
                      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                             

                       content: contentString
                          

});

                         



 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, i) {
                            


  return function () {
                            

      infowindow.open(map, marker);

                         

                  }
                          })(marker, i));
                        

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function (marker, i) {
                            


  return function () {
                            


      infowindow.close();
                         

     }
                         

 })(marker, i));
                

  })
               

 }  

     </script>
</div>
```

This is my code with search content. And through database when alert=0 no pulse will show on Google Map. And when alert=1 a pulse animation will show on Google Map.

But I want to show that pulse animation with the help of ajax.

Comment: Readers want to help, but this is rather broad. It looks like you want to start using AJAX, but don't know where to begin. That's OK, but someone is unlikely to write the code for you. It is better if you can do some research, try something, and then show us what you have tried. Do you know what endpoint you want to contact?

Comment: Taking the time to remove extra space and do some nicer formatting when you post code will help readers to read your question, which will help your post get responses.

Comment: this is edited code version ...  i have made search but no such code was available and i have no idea about ajax